# CKEditor5 drop event is not adding object

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ckeditor5

I have the latest CKEditor5 (40.2.0) in an Angular solution. I use the InLineEditor. The Clipboard plugin is installed. Everything is added with NPM.

In my solution I have a list of objects that I want to drag to the editor. Just like the demopage on CKEditors own site [ckeditor5 drag-n-drop demo](https://(https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/drag-drop.html#balloon-block-editor-demo)). This demo just demonstrates how the objects are dragged to the editor. It doesn't show what to do to drop the object. So in my case I can see that the dragging works fine. The `dataTransfer.setData` works fine. The `event.dataTransfer.getData` works fine in the drop function. Btw, I have added my own drop function since this is not documented in the demo.

The thing is that I have all my data in the drop function, but it doesn't drop in the editor. If I stop the debugger in the drop function it tells me that I have all the data I want. Then I set my data to `event.target.value = myData`, but it is not added to the editor. I am doing it bit other than the demo regarding the event listners, but it should be the same outcome.

Anyone knows why? My first thought is that the editor doesn't like for anything to be dragged over.

The ckeditor in my html file:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor"
  #ckeditor
  [data]="editor5Data"
  (ready)="onCKEditor5Ready($event)"
  (change)="onCKEditor5Change($event)"
  (drop)="onCKEditor5Drop($event)"
  (dragover)="onCKEditor5AllowDrop($event)">
 </ckeditor>
```

My draggable object:

```
<div class="h-card drag-object-container current-drag-object" attr.data-contact="{{blokk.id}}" 
   draggable="true" (dragstart)="onCKEditor5Drag($event)" tabindex="{{i}}">
</div>
```

This is my drag event:

```
onCKEditor5Drag(event){
  var target = (event.target as HTMLElement).closest('div')
  var dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
  dataTransfer.setData('contact', target.dataset['contact']);
}
```

This is my drop event (with just a test string):

```
onCKEditor5Drop(event){
    const id = event.dataTransfer.getData("contact");
    event.target.value = id;
    event.preventDefault();
}
```